# Reusing stream of sed for string append

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, sed

**TL;DR: Need to reuse stream in sed so that extracted string is added into current line's ending.**

I have have a script to `extract` a substring using sed and make a command to copy using this substring's name.

There are few things I tried such as xargs, but `sed -e` parses each line separately and reinvoking sed reads all lines again for every line currently being parsed:

This line below just prints out the string extracted:

```
cat hello.txt | sed -e 's/.*search_start\(.*\)search_end*/\1/' | xargs -I@ "echo ./@"
```

This line creates a string with copy command added for folder `location`:

```
cat hello.txt | sed -e 's/\(^\)/copy /; s/$/ .\/location/;'
```

However, I want to add these together so that the `extracted_str` searched string can be referenced in place of `location` folder here.
So, I need something like this (for each line):

```
copy input_sed_line extracted_str
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an example of what ```hello.txt``` contains and what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, you need an extra occurrence of the whole line along with whatever `sed` extracts from it. Well, `sed` can print the whole line with `p`, so this is possible:

```
< hello.txt sed -e 'p; s/.*search_start\(.*\)search_end.*/\1/' | xargs -d '\n' -n 2 copy --
```

Notes:

- Whatever `copy` is (did you mean `cp`?).
- I assumed `copy` understands `--` (the end of options marker).
- I fixed the useless use of `cat`.
- I assumed `search_end*` should be `search_end.*`.
- `-d` and `-n` options of `xargs` are not required by POSIX. See `man 1 xargs` in your OS to tell if you can use them. Here `-d '\n'` specifies the newline character as delimiter, `-n 2` tells `xargs` to use exactly two input items per `copy`. `-n`, if supported, is probably somewhat limited.

---

The above may work in many cases, but if I were you I would use a shell and its `read` builtin. It's true one [shouldn't loop `read` to parse text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/108618); `sed`, `awk` and such are the right tools in general. Here however your goal is not only to parse text. Your goal is to craft and run commands. A shell like `sh` or `bash` is the right tool to run commands.

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r wholeline; do
   target="$(printf '%s\n' "$wholeline" | sed -e 's/.*search_start\(.*\)search_end.*/\1/')"
   copy -- "$wholeline" "$target"
done < hello.txt
```

The code runs a separate `sed` process for each line. In your case this can be easily avoided:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r wholeline; do
   target="${wholeline##*search_start}"   # removing prefix
   target="${target%%search_end*}"        # removing postfix
   copy -- "$wholeline" "$target"
done < hello.txt
```

---

One could do (almost) the same with `awk`:

```
< hello.txt awk '{
   target=$0
   sub(/.*search_start/,"",target)
   sub(/search_end.*/,"",target)
   cmdline="copy -- '"'"'"$0"'"' '"'"target"'"'"'"
   system(cmdline)
   }'
```

There are problems though:

1. Quoting frenzy. There are three levels that need quotes and interpret them: the original shell where `awk` is invoked, `awk` itself, the shell invoked by `system()`. One can get rid of the first level by building an `awk` script (with the shebang like `#!/usr/bin/awk`). Still it's cumbersome. I'm not even sure I placed these quotes exactly as I wanted.
2. `cmdline` is passed as a string which is then *parsed*, not as an array of arguments. If the input contains the literal `'` character then things will break, some parts of the input may get executed (code injection!).
3. `system(cmdline)` invokes `sh`, additional separate shell for every single line. You can `print cmdline` instead, then pipe the whole output to a single `sh` (or save to a file to parse it later). This will reduce the number of processes but the previous problem will stay: the textual output will be *parsed* sooner or later.

From my experience I can say these problems are not limited to `awk`. If you want to use any tool to run an external command with arguments based on arbitrary input, pay attention whether it passes a string (to be parsed by `sh` or anything) or spawns a new process with strictly defined array of arguments. E.g. `find -exec` does the latter (or at least common implementations of `find` do).

---

Conclusions:

- `xargs` may lack useful options.
- Text processing tools are better than shells in processing text, but they are usually a lot worse in running external commands.

For this reasons I think a shell loop is at least reasonable here. Still you should read good answers to the [already linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/108618). Note my shell script doesn't follow all the hints you can find there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer Kamil! This worked great. I had produced an alternate solution using xargs @1, @1 using bash to echo piped commands. But this (sed -e `p` ) is a better solution.

Comment: Adding a tiny detail to your query on copy vs cp, I had been using UNIX binaries to execute on Windows cmd, hence the usage of `copy` in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Why not:

```
location=$(cat hello.txt | sed -e 's/.*search_start\(.*\)search_end*/\1/' | xargs -I@ "echo ./@")
cat hello.txt | sed -e 's/\(^\)/copy /; s/$/ .\/'"$location"'/;'
```

Comment: The location is supposed to be different for each line. Correct me if I am wrong, this current command would store just the last line's `location`

Comment: The substring extraction will find all occurences. $location is going to be a multiline variable.  You may need to put in a -0 in your xargs though if location is one line.

Comment: @Davey - if it's a "_multiline variable_", then `$location` will expand to such in the second line... which is broken?